# comparing array strings

Tags: java, arrays, list

The user enters an array of numbers such as "123456789"
and then the user is supposed to enter a string of commands such as "PE"
and my program will check each character in the string.

P = Remove the last number entered, which is 9
E = Prints out the final result.

To this point everything was working fine.

But my problem is that I have to be able to read the command when the user inputs "P(any number)", and I have to place that number at the end of the array of numbers.

So if it was P(4), the result would be "1234567894".

How can I do this ?

This is what I have right now for P and E.

```
if (commandList.get(x).equals("P(")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "HI");
}
else if (commandList.get(x).equals("P")) {
    strList.remove(strList.size()-1);
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Is your number array  integer type or string type? However you can try using this `commandList.get(x).contains("P(")`

Comment: It seems you have a List, not an array. Please edit for clarity

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, your problem is to *extract* the '*digit*' from the string "P(*digit*)" ?

Well you have to parse the input string, e.g., by searching for bounding characters, here '(' and ')'. For example by something like that:

```
String s = "P(3)";
String number = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf(")"));
strList.append(number);
```

But this would also accept *anything* within the bracktes, e.g., "foooo" from "P(foooo)", and it would crash if ')' cannot be found, e.g., s = "P(123", and it would accept "P(3)blah54" which is strictly spoken invalid. To improve your parser, you can use regular expressions, e.g., to check if the input is exactly of the form "P(2)" for exactly a single digit, you can use

```
String s = "P(3)";
if (!s.matches("P\\(\\d\\)"))
    throw new RuntimeException("invalid input format: " + s);
String number = s.substring(s.indexOf("(") + 1, s.indexOf(")"));
strList.append(number);
```

If you explicitly want to cast the digit to an int, you might have a look at Integer.parseInt(...), e.g.,

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(number);
```